# What service will copy a third-party JSON feed every few seconds so users can access the copy?

Tags: javascript, json, feed, firebase

I'm using an API to access a JSON feed, but the makers of the feed say too many people are using my service. So I need a third party to make a copy of the feed every few seconds, letting users access the copy, not the original. What services do this?

I found  Firebase, but it's designed to copy user-created data that users are actively pushing to it. So I would need some sort of separate service that tells Firebase over and over to update its data, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Feed the Fire](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-25-rss-to-firebase.html), which reads RSS feeds into Firebase. I think you'll find it a great idea bank and a close fit for your needs. Essentially, it uses a node.js process to read the source feeds on a regular interval and inject them into Firebase for consumption.

The code involved is rather trivial:

```
Var Firebase = require('firebase');

setInterval(function() {

   var jsonData = /* get data from your JSON feed */;

   new Firebase(URL).set( jsonData );

}, FREQUENCY_OF_CHECK_IN_MILLISECONDS );
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It looks like Feed the Fire is specifically made for RSS and Atom feeds. Will it work for any JSON or XML feed as well?

Comment: Rss (I.e. xml) or json are simply the payload. Take those 6 lines above, plug in you json data, and consult ftf's node script for more ideas and examples.

Comment: This: new Firebase('https://myaccount.firebaseio.com/').set('http://myjsonserver.com/file.json'); ... populates my firebase with the mere string that is the URL of my JSON file, rather than the file's contents. And set(http://myjsonserver.com/file.json) without quotes results in an error. XMLHttpRequest doesn't seem to work, even after I npm install xmlhttprequest and require it correctly. I keep getting an error about how XMLHttpRequest's "open" property inherently contains the argument "contents", which itself contains a function. So how do I get the contents of a remote file into Firebase?

Comment: Okay, wow! I made it work! I made this completely foreign group of things -- node.js, Firebase, Linux-like command prompts -- work! I can populate my Firebase with JSON data. But node.js just hangs permanently afterward, apparently not knowing if the file is done downloading. I usually add a callback parameter to the URL to fix this, but that's not doing anything here. You wouldn't happen to know what to do about that? Maybe I need to ask a new question.

Comment: You are using chlid_added or a similar command that is holding the node.js process open. Try on('value') or similar, which does not listen indefinitely on the opened connection : )